# Are there any apps to see what makes an iPhone app size large?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My iPhone app has recently got a little larger than I'd like (nearing 100MB) and I'm not entirely sure what the cause of it is.

There are many apps for the Mac like DaisyDisk that let you see the make up of your Mac's storage, but is there something where I can see what's taking up so much space in, say, a .ipa file?

Comment: unzip your ipa file and check the size of everything?

Comment: @BryanChen That's def an option but I was hoping for something a little more automated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryan's answer is the way to go. Unzip your IPA (Rename it from .ipa to .zip), find the .app file in the unzipped folder, option click the .app file and view contents, press command J and check "calculate all file sizes", and then sort the results by file size. More than likely you have big media files in your app.

If you try this with iMovie, for example, you'll find the the largest folder in the app is called "Assets", and it's 261 MB.

Comment: The app is around 100MB, but the only "assets" file I can find is "Assets.car" which is only 5MB. There's a "Unix executable file" matching my app's name that is 70MB, however. How do I see what causes it to be so large?

Comment: That is the machine code for your app. It's probably a universal binary, which will make it appear big. Make sure you've enabled Bitcode, which will cause the app store to only deliver install the machine code for the specific device, and should cause the unix executable file to be about 1/3 the size on an actual device.

Comment: I only used the "assets" folder in the iMovie app as an example. Look at the files and folders in your app in order from largest to smallest. That will let you quickly identify the things that contribute to the size of your app.

Comment: Since your binary size increased, did you add any static libraries lately?